# atmega2650 toggling OC1C (led on arduino mega)

Tags: timer, arduino, atmega

I am trying to toggle an LED with a 1024 prescaler, CTC mode 4.

The LED comes on after a second and stays on.

What am I doing wrong?

```cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
    
void setup() {
  //PORTB ^= (0 << PB7);
  DDRB = (1 << PB7);
  TCNT1 = 0;
  OCR1C = 100;
    
  TCCR1A = 0; // thought maybe arduino was setting other bits?
  TCCR1B = 0; //
    
  TCCR1A = (0 << COM1C1) | (1 << COM1C0) | (0 << WGM11) | (0 << WGM10);
  TCCR1B = (0 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS12) | (0 << CS11) | (1 << CS10);
}
    
void loop() {}
```

UPDATE

```cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
    
void setup() {
  //PORTB ^= (0 << PB7);
  DDRB = (1 << PB7);
  TCNT1 = 0;
  
    
  TCCR1A = 0; // 
  TCCR1B = 0; //

  OCR1A = 100; // OCR1A is the CTC mode 4 top

    
  TCCR1A = (0 << COM1C1) | (1 << COM1C0) | (0 << WGM11) | (0 << WGM10);
  TCCR1B = (0 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS12) | (0 << CS11) | (1 << CS10);
}
    
void loop() {}
```

Set OCR1A after clearing the TCCR1A and TCCR1B

As Mike said OCR1A is top for mode 4

Comment: Doesn't WGM mode 4 use OCR1A as the "top" value for the counter? I don't see that set anywhere. I'd have to re-read the datasheet again to be sure...

Comment: Yes you are correct. I went back and forth because I did not see any change. It seems where I cleared the bits on TCCR1A and TCCR1B most likely set or clears a flag? and erases my OCR1A value.